# Android 11, Not able to open exist docx file using intent

Tags: android, android-studio

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +    "/Download/NSuresh.docx" );     uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +    ".provider", file);   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");   startActivity(intent);

Comment: Do you have any Docx reader application in your device??

Comment: did you add file provider in manifest?